# Using jquery to show next div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I am using colorbox.js to display some forms in a lightbox. There are multiple forms on a page and each form has a link that will open the form in the lightbox. Right now, the lightbox will open but the form will not be showing. Here is my jquery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.myForm').hide();

        $('.link_to_form').click( function() { $(this).next('.myForm').show() } );

        $(".link_to_form").colorbox({ 
            width: "50%", 
            inline: true,
            opacity: ".5", 
            href: ".myForm", 
            onClosed: function() {
                $(".myForm").hide();
            }

            });
    });
```

My HTML for two forms and two links is:

```
<a href="#" class="link_to_form">Form 1</a>
<div class="myForm">
<form></form>
</div>
<a href="#" class="link_to_form">Form 2</a>
<div class="myForm">
<form></form>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried a JSFiddle and it works ok for me. Maybe the problem is in the rest of your markup?

Comment: Is the html you provided us with abridged?  If that is the full code you should be aware there is nothing in the forms. (that might explain why you think it is showing up empty)  The other thing I notice quite often is that events that toggle visibility of something that is within another jquery widget need to be 100% sure the containing element is visible on the screen before changing the insides. (usually this is done with a callback from something like 'onOpen').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2anwK/3/

**script**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.benariac.fr/fabien/jsfiddle/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.benariac.fr/fabien/jsfiddle/colorbox/colorbox/colorbox.css">
```

**code**

```
$('.myForm').hide();

$('.link_to_form').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.myForm').show()
});

$(".link_to_form").colorbox({
    width: "50%",
    inline: true,
    opacity: ".5",
    href: ".myForm",
    onClosed: function() {
        $(".myForm").hide();
    }

});
```

**Working Image**

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable. That is exactly what I need to happen and I am still not able to get it to work on my site. Could it possibly be a CSS issue?

Comment: @user715564 no worries, Glad it helpd `:)` yes by the looks of it or your src of script

Comment: Ok, I checked and after clicking the link, the "myForm" class still has the css set to display:none where as in your example, clicking the link changes the css class of myForm to display:block. That means it's a jquery problem right?

Comment: @user715564 I doubt bruv if it Jquery issue, check your DOM again might be something small, `:)` hmm interesting though

Comment: Not a jQuery issue, take a look my answer.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann lol I know; was just being polite to OP `:P` thnka for comment though!

Comment: Ok I checked the DOM and didn't see anything. Of course the small details could be floating past my blurry eyes. Here is the html before clicking on a link http://imgur.com/czrj5

Comment: @user715564 `:)` I hope you are not missing the colorbox source? like this `<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.benariac.fr/fabien/jsfiddle/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Nope I have it loaded. I am using jquery.colorbox-min.js and loading it off of my server.

Comment: @user715564 okies, can you make a small jsfiddle using demo above, I might take a look bruv, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do:

You can take a look the [reference](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/) to see how to implement.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#myForm1" class="link_to_form colorbox">Form 1</a>
<div id="myForm1" class="myForm">
    <form>
        <p>text1</p>
    </form>
</div>
<a href="#myForm2" class="link_to_form colorbox">Form 2</a>
<div id="myForm2" class="myForm">
    <form>
        <p>text2</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(".link_to_form").on('click', function() {
    var $self = $(this),
        $popup = $self.next('.myForm');
    $self.colorbox({
        width: "50%",
        inline: true,
        opacity: "0.5",
        onOpen: function() {
            $popup.show();
        },
        onClosed: function() {
            $popup.hide();
        }

    });
});
```

**css**

```
.myForm{
    display: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vuDC/163/)

Comment: Thanks for the help Ricardo. The only problem is the form is in two divs and I really need for it to only be in one (for client ease). Is there anyway we could get around the two different divs?

Comment: I don't the popup class anywhere in the html though?

Comment: The CMS I am using is enclosing the link elements in a <p> tag so it is <p><a href...></a></p>. Would that affect anything or keep it from working?